# Only show every nth axis tick marks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to group the dots by assigning my categorical data specific x- and y-values with empty spaces in between. Instead of showing every single tick mark on the axes,

[image: plot with ticks]

or showing no ticks at all,

[image: plot with no ticks]

I would like to show only every nth tick mark on the axes corresponding to the labels. Can this be done in ggplot? Or maybe there is a different approach to generate the plot I am looking for.

Comment: Please add data and code used to generate above plot. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to S.O. Please could you edit the images in this post so that they are cropped? There's a lot of unnecessary whitespace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without a reproducible example. You could try adding a `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()` statement.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10),labels=c("0","2","4","6","8","10"))
```